# Replicated Caching and File Systes back Up in Hazelcast

Tags: hazelcast

I have following queries regarding Hazelcast :

1. Does replicated caching possible with Hazelcast, I mean is it possible to start 3 nodes with all of these nodes will have all of the keys? Another related question is that if I start two nodes both of the nodes will have all the keys.. right?
2. Is it possible to have file system back up in Hazelcast, I mean if all nodes go down is it possible to have back up in file system?

Thanks,
Abhinav

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1: Replicated cache is something planned for Hazelcast 3.2. So currently it is partitioned, although you can configure a nearcache so that a member can cache values. We hope to release Hazelcast at the beginning of next year and hopefully this feature is part of it (a few customers want it).

2: Currently we don't have support for it. But.. our lead architect is working on the API. But this is a big task, so will not be part of 3.2, but more likely 3.3 or maybe even 3.4.

Peter.

Comment: Thanks Peter!! Currently If I start two Hazelcast nodes, It will behave like replicated caching only.. Am I right?

Comment: If you start e.g. 4 nodes, every node will contain 25% of the data (and it will also contain 25% of the backups). So the Hazelcast Map is partitioned, not replicated.

If you enable the nearcache option and say it is allowed e.g. to be 10k big, then each member can contain 10k cached items, next to its 25% of the partitioned items.

Comment: I am exactly interested in Abhinav's Question #2. Peter I have just started exploring Hazelcast and the plan is to use it for caching web session of application and also have flie sytem back to handle worst case scenario i.e. Situation when all nodes go down. Is it available in latest release "hazelcast-3.3-EA" or not yet?

Comment: We don't have this functionality available yet; guys are working on it. But it will be part of the HZ enterprise edition if I remember correctly.